# The Richardson Effect (formula)

Tags: notation, fractals

I am a software programmer who needs help embedding "The Richardson Effect" formula for a calculation on a series of XY data points. I know how to program, but I need help with how to read the formula.

Lewis Fry Richardson (1881 – 1953), The coastline paradox

Here is the formula:
$$\log[L(s)] = (1 - D)\log(s) + b$$

"D" is the Fractal Dimension, But I do not know what "L", "s", and "b" are, or how to determine them.

If someone could walk me through this formula, I'll be all set.

Answer (score 3):

$L(s)$ is the coast length when measured with at ruler of length $s$. The constant $b$ is determined empirically with a linear regression or theoretically with a given fractal type.

If using the empirical regression route you need a number of points $(s,L)$ to fit the line
$$
\log L(s) =(1−D)\log s +b.
$$
The intercept will give you $b$ and the slope will give you $(1-D)$.

For more reference see e.g. Wikipedia and http://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/psychology/cogsci/chaos/workshop/Fractals.html

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! Can you expand on "b"? Preferring the linear regression route... what exactly is the linear regression being applied to?

Comment: @Chuckv Does that help?

Comment: Yes, we're close... TY for your patience. Using my XY data set, in my mind, I only end up with 1 value... what exactly am I doing to get multiple values (from the same data set) that I can obtain a slope from?

Comment: You need to vary the ruler length $s$ and repeat the coast length measure for different values, each value of $s$ will give you a different $L$.

Comment: I understand now. TY.